# Ubuntu 11.10 sound comes from everywhere

Tags: audio, ubuntu-11.10

Why is the sound coming from my laptop and my TV at the same time? I tried every little guide/tip out there and nothing happens.

For reference I have a Asus laptop that is connected to a Samsung TV (using this as my screen).

**EDIT** I give up! I've tried for two days now every guide on the internet. I guess ubuntu is not for everyone

Comment: What cable are you using from your laptop to your TV? I assume HDMI?

Comment: At the moment no (all my 4 HDMI ports are taken). So it's connected with a audio cable and a vga cable.

Comment: I had an ASUS G51VX laptop a few years ago that did this as well. It turned out to be an Alsa Config issue. Sorry I can't be more specific, but don't have the model number of your laptop.

Answer (score 2):

*How* have you connected to the TV? Via a HDMI cable?

Some (if not all) HDMI cables and devices transfer both audio and video over HDMI, so your computer might be using the TV not only as monitor but also as speaker because this is the default setting when plugging in an HDMI device.

Try going to Sound (under System Settings) and changing the selected hardware output to your speakers/headphone jack. (Mine is called "Analog Stereo Duplex". Unfortunately I'm on the wrong computer at the moment, so I can't give you any screenshots...)